# Manipulating html formatted text to paste clipboard data without the format

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `contenteditable="true"` div . The user can copy/past text from various sources (ctrl C / right mouse click) and paste into it. The issue is that when the user does so, the formatted text gets pasted instead of plaintext, which is undesirable. I could have simply called `$("theDiv").html($("theDiv").text())`, but I have some other `<span>` tags in the div that I want to preserve.

Some googling tells me that there is no straightforward way to extract the text content out of the clipboard data (please correct me here). The alternative then is to cleanse the content of my div post pasting. Lets take the example:

Before Pasting (A):

```
<span class="linkText2">Life</span>&nbsp;<span class="linkText3">is</span>&nbsp;good&nbsp;
```

After Pasting (B):

```
<span class="linkText2">Life</span>&nbsp;<span class="linkText3">is&nbsp;<span style="white-space: normal; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 128, 0.0745098);">very</span></span>good&nbsp;
```

What I want instead is (C):

```
<span class="linkText2">Life</span>&nbsp;<span class="linkText3">is&nbsp;very</span>good&nbsp;
```

To achieve this, the algorithm is to replace all elements in the DOM tree constructed by (B) that are anything but a `<span class="linkText[0-9]+">` with its plaintext value.

I tried the following:

```
$.each($.parseHTML($("#theDiv").html()), function(index, value) {
  console.log(index +':'+value);
});
```

which gives me the output in Chrome debugger as:

```
0:[object HTMLSpanElement]
1:[object Text]
2:[object HTMLSpanElement]
3:[object Text]
4:[object HTMLSpanElement]
```

It may be okay to iterate through this array, but it is not a jQuery type solution, and appears getting more complicated than I had thought. I am somehow trying to use .replaceWith(newContent) or similar. Can someone point me in the correct direction. Regex may also do the job, but I am desperately short of time to try it out.

Thanks in advance